# ADF CI/CD Incremental deployment -just the changed pipelines not the whole ADF

Tags: continuous-integration, cd

I am Working on **Azure** Devops and building `CI/CD` pipelines for azure data approach provided by the Microsoft.and this will create Whole **ADF** and its Entities in test/prod Environments. Where ever we deploy the ARM templates,but we just want to deploy changed pipelines not the Whole **ADF**.

The Approach i know is :

> Configure the ADF with GIT-->Merge to Master-->publish to ADF_publish
>   branch-->setup

CI/CD pipeline to use the template &Parameters jsons to respective test/Prod Environments.

The Ask is"How to deploy just the `ADF` Pipelines/Datasets/linked Services /Triggers that has changed. if there is no changes to other entities don't deploy.

can someone kindly suggest me the best approach .

Comment: Microsoft's approach does not support the incremental or partial deployment of ADF right now, although ARM template deployments are always deltas. Why is it important for you? What's your case?  
In the meantime, you might be interested in another approach to deployment ADF - directly from code: [azure.datafactory.tools](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools)  
Next version I'm planning to implement an option to include/exclude objects to be deployed and in the feature includes the deployment of changed objects only. Any comments welcomed.